# SafeSEH and x64

Tags: windows, exploit, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9a89h429%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that

> /SAFESEH is only valid when linking for x86 targets. /SAFESEH is not
>   supported for platforms that already have the exception handlers
>   noted. For example, on x64 and Itanium, all exception handlers are
>   noted in the PDATA.

What does this mean? Is the SEH chain checked with a x64 target (stored into the PDATA structure) ? Or there is no safeSEH check with x64 targets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SafeSEH is a mechanism that protects stack-based exception handler chains from being overwritten. However, on x64 and Itanium architectures, the exception handlers are table-based (i.e. stored in PDATA) and therefore cannot be overwritten directly by a stack buffer overflow - they're simply not on the stack. As such, SafeSEH is irrelevant to those systems.